# Selecting data in a view and inserting them in Users database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading the contact informations of users from `Outlook API`, and I would like to add them to my Users database using a `submit_tag` approach. But it does not work. So far my form on `index.html.erb` looks like:

```
<h1>My contacts</h1>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>

<%= form_tag import_contacts_path, method: :put do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import Selected contact" %>

  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= check_box_tag "contact_ids[]", 'Select' %></td>
        <td><%= contact.given_name %></td>
      <td><%= contact.surname %></td>
      <td><%= !contact.email_addresses[0].nil? ? contact.email_addresses[0].address : '' %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
    <%= submit_tag "Import Selected contactact" %>
<% end %>
```

My ContactController looks like:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  include AuthHelper

  def index
    token = get_access_token
    if token
      # If a token is present in the session, get contacts
      callback = Proc.new do |r|
        r.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{token}"
      end

      graph = MicrosoftGraph.new(base_url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0',
                                 cached_metadata_file: File.join(MicrosoftGraph::CACHED_METADATA_DIRECTORY, 'metadata_v1.0.xml'),
                                 &callback)

      @contacts = graph.me.contacts.order_by('givenName asc')
    else
      # If no token, redirect to the root url so user
      # can sign in.
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def import
    User.create(:first_name => @contacts.givenName , :last_name => @contacts.surname, :email => @contacts.email_addresses)
    redirect_to imported_path
  end

end
```

I can read my contact information without any problem, but when i try clicking on the button to import a selection of contact, I have the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `givenName' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:26:in `import'
```

My routes look like

```
   resources 'contacts' do
      collection do
        put :import
      end
```

Does anyone knows if it is actually possible to create such import function ? Because  i am trying to read something that is not on a local database actually.

Answer (score 0):

You have called @contacts in

```
def import
   User.create(:first_name => @contacts.givenName , :last_name => @contacts.surname, :email => @contacts.email_addresses)
redirect_to imported_path
end
```

But you have not define @contacts. Since @contacts is nil and you are calling givenName to nil it is giving error. Can you specify @contacts within import method or before filter so that it would be available with in that method.
Hope defining @contacts will fix the issue. If the issue still exist let me know.

Please check the params, in params the value must have come you can use something like

```
def import
   User.create(:first_name => params[:givenName] , :last_name => params[:surname], :email => params[:email_addresses])
   redirect_to imported_path
end
```

Try this one and let me know if there is any issue. Or you can send what params that comes.

Comment: I am stuck at the same place. I defined the @contact just like I did in the `index` but i do not have fields names since it is not an actual db.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the following function in the controller:

```
 def import_contact(contact)
    Contact.create(email: !contact.email_addresses[0].nil? ? contact.email_addresses[0].address : '', first_name: contact.given_name, last_name: contact.surname, user_id: current_user )

    return !contact.email_addresses[0].nil? ? contact.email_addresses[0].address : ''
  end
```

and the the view calls the function:   `<%= import_contact(contact) %>`

This way i unfortunately do not select which conctact i want to import. I import all of them, but that is the best i could find now.